# Laravel Broadcasting with Pusher isn't Listening with Vue

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, pusher, laravel-echo, pusher-js

With Laravel (v5.7) I'm trying to get Broacasting to Work with Pusher and Vue.

The App is like a Chat. When there is a message send in a private chat, the following function is called:
`broadcast(new NewChat($message));`

This is the "NewChat"-Event:

```
class NewChat implements ShouldBroadcast
{
    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithSockets, SerializesModels;

    public $message;

    public function __construct(\App\Message $message)
    {
        $this->message = $message;
    }

    public function broadcastOn()
    {
        return new PrivateChannel('chats.' . $this->message->conversation_id);
    }

    public function broadcastWith()
    {
        return ['message' => $this->message];
    }
}
```

The `channels.php` has:

```
Broadcast::channel('chats.{conversationId}', function ($user, $conversationId) {
    return true; // security i'll do later
});
```

It sends it all to Pusher:
[image]

But I can't figure out how to correctly listen to the Events with Vue and update it all.
The following I've added in the boostrap.js (it's all written in Vue the app):

```
import Echo from 'laravel-echo'
window.Pusher = require('pusher-js');
window.Echo = new Echo({
    broadcaster: 'pusher',
    key: process.env.MIX_PUSHER_APP_KEY,
    cluster: process.env.MIX_PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER, 
    encrypted: true
});
window.Echo.private(`chats.1`)
    .listen('NewChat', (e) => {
        console.log(e);
    });
```

In the example I hardcoded the number 1 for the private channel, because that's the same channel as from the screenshot.

What am I missing? I re-read the documentation page multiple times and tried following tutorials to see if I've skipped something small, but don't know.
Anyone who sees what I'm missing?

Comment: In Chrome dev tools, do you see a successful `broadcasting/auth` XHR call? Also, how does the `WS` (Web socket) tab look like in Chrome dev tools? Does it have a connection established frame?

Comment: @Paras Yes, I see that (https://www.dropbox.com/s/puw7q2cjsukcptr/Schermafdruk%202018-10-30%2010.25.29.png?dl=0) and when sending a message I see this in the WS tab: https://www.dropbox.com/s/vu20bvkf4zu13zv/Schermafdruk%202018-10-30%2010.26.41.png?dl=0 - but nothing more. In Pusher.com it all looks good and sees the connections and messages correctly.

Comment: I figured out that WS does more in a live environment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/n1v5gstsw0txqfv/Schermafdruk%202018-10-30%2011.34.25.png?dl=0 - but still nothing printed in my console of new chats

Comment: Do you see a `broadcasting/auth` XHR call?

Comment: @Paras double checked it and it doens't show up online iindeed on the live server.

Comment: Try to temporarily change using private channels to public ones. Perhaps, you forgot to add `authEndpoint` (and implement it).

Answer (score -2):

Based on your responses in comments, your `broadcasting/auth` request call is not fired. This seems to suggest that your Laravel Echo code in your `bootstrap.js` file is not being called.

One way you can test this is simply add a `console.log` in your `bootstrap.js` file. Possible reasons could be a) missed deployment script run, b) your app entry point doesn't call `bootstrap.js`.

If you have missed deployment script run, just run `npm run prod` to fix the issue.

Comment: thank you. I added on top now of the bootstrap.js that console logger and the information is showed in the console. So the bootstrap is included correctly. How to fix/check #B?

Comment: Add a `console.log(window.Echo.options)` after echo initialization and check if your key and cluster show up properly. Also, do you see any errors related to Echo in your console?

Comment: ```{broadcaster: "pusher", key: "xxxxx", cluster: "eu", encrypted: true}``` - no errors in the console. BUT now I found something out: the console things in bootstrap.js are showing up on my local dev machine, but not on the production live server. Is that maybe something?

Comment: Yes, that means that you possibly missed deployment on the production server. Did you run `npm run prod`?

Comment: no, I didn't ;-) But when I did, It indeed showed the console like it did locally. I checked in the console if the socket was running and it is: socket_id: 125244.3578055 and channel_name: private-chats.1 > so that's correct, right?

Comment: No, it's still not working. My expectation is that there is something printed in the console when a message is sent. In both browsers. But it doesn't. Even when I do an alert() in the listen(), it doesn't show either.

Comment: So now the `broadcasting/auth` XHR call is visible and the `WS` tab shows the frames for the channel?

Comment: Yes, that auth XHR call is visible and showint the socket and channel name. The WS tab does things when I submit new messages to the chat. But only in the browser where it's send from. Not the other one that also has the chat open.

Comment: What is the channel through which the message is sent? Is it the `chats.1` channel? Is the recipient browser also listening to the same `chats.1` channel?

Comment: In chrome XHR at the auth route: ```channel_name: private-chats.1```. In Pusher: ```Channel: private-chats.2, Event: App\Events\NewChat``` and the Listen in Vue: ```window.Echo.private(`chats.2`).listen('NewChat', (e) => {
```

Comment: Sounds like the message is sent to a different channel than the channel listened to one the recipient end

Comment: The sender must send the message to the same channel that the recipient is listening to

Comment: Oh sorry, that was a typo. It's both sending and listening on the same channel.

Comment: That's strange, one last try. Try adding `public function broadcastAs() { return 'test';}` in your event class and changing the Vue code to `.listen('.test')` and see if it works. Don't forget the dot before test in the `listen` call. It isnt a typo

Comment: Sorry buddy, out of ideas now :)